# Terminating OpenVPN after disconnect - how to disable reconnecting

Tags: networking, firewall, openvpn

I want my OpenVPN client application (running on *A*) to *quit* when it is unable to connect (or reconnect) to a server (*B*). I use the UDP protocol. Both *A* and *B* are Linux systems.

More precisely, I keep on getting the following log entries.

```
UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET] [remote-ip]
TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Re-using SSL/TLS context
UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET] [remote-ip]
...
```

I know why *A* cannot access *B*. Instead of restarting the process, I want OpenVPN to quit.

There are some options in `man openvpn` that I tried using.

- I set `resolv-retry` to a small number (not working, the address of *B* can be resolved).
- I set `connect-retry-max` to 1 (not working, I am using UDP).

I am guessing that I am looking over some option....

EDIT: Background info:
I want to do this because of firewall hole punching. *B* is behind a firewall that allows only SSH traffic. Before starting the client on *A*, I run a script that enables traffic to flow from *A* to *B*. This works for a while, but the hole in *B*'s firewall needs to be 'renewed' after some time (e.g. due to network problems, but also because *A* has a dynamic IP address). Since there is no `up-pre` counterpart to `down-pre` and I do not want to apply [a patch](https://digitaldj.net/blog/2013/09/09/a-pre-connect-patch-for-openvpn/) and compile OpenVPN myself to add it, I run a wrapper script on *A* that punches a new hole (in *B*'s firewall) and starts OpenVPN each time OpenVPN stops running. This would work, if only OpenVPN were to quit....

Comment: Is it an option to just "mute 5" in the config to supress multiple log entries?

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not. I need the process to end. I added some background information to my question to explain why I need this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the --down directive to the OpenVpn config to call a script when OpenVpn closes the tunnel. That script can close the application, or event better - sit around trying to reinitialize the hole-punching directly.